# Haskell - Maybe/Just Recursion

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I read some Postings and Blogs about monads, maybe, just, nothing.. but didn`t really get it :/
In the given code, I have to implement the "latestActivity"-function.
To my mind it should work but I have no idea how to use "Just" correctly. Maybe someone is able to help me.

```
module LatestActivity where
{-
Write a function 'latestActivity' that finds that last time a specific user
has sent a message. It is given a user name and a list of messages. A message
consists of the time it was sent, the user name of the user who sent it and
the message content. If there is no message from the given user in the list
the function yields 'Nothing'. Otherwise it yields 'Just' the latest time stamp
of the messages of that user in the list.
-}

import Data.List (sort)

-- | A time stamp represented as an 'Integer'
type AbsoluteTime = Integer
-- | A user name represented as a 'String'
type UserName = String

-- | A message consists of the time it was sent, the user who sent it
--   and the actual message content.
data Message = Message {
    _timeStamp :: AbsoluteTime,
    _userName :: UserName,
    _messageContent :: String}

-- | Given a user name and a list of sent messages finds 'Just' the last time
--   a user has sent a message or 'Nothing' if the user has not sent anything.
--   The messages are not assumed to be ordered in any way.
latestActivity :: UserName -> [Message] -> Maybe AbsoluteTime
latestActivity _ [] = Nothing 
latestActivity x y = 
    if (x == (_userName (last y)))      -- x equals username in last list element?
        then (_timeStamp (last y))      -- print it
        else (latestActivity x init y)  -- otherwise delete last listelement, recursion till list is empty
```

Comment: You should provide more details of what problems you have with your current solution, such as any error messages you get from the compiler or incorrect behaviour at runtime. Without this information it is much more time-consuming for people to see what you are doing wrong and help you.

Answer (score 5):

@rightfold gives a possible solution, but note that your approach is not very idiomatic Haskell. "otherwise delete last listelement" is procedural thinking, not a way you want to reason about a Haskell function. That's not really happening in your code anyway, you can't delete stuff in Haskell but need to build a new list each iteration: as a result, it's extremely inefficient, since both `last` and `init` need to traverse the entire list before anything else can be done.

Basically, what you're doing is a *search* through the list, back-to-front. So the obvious first thing to do is, reverse the list so you can search front-to-back as you're used to (and lists are optimised for).

```
latestActivity user = earliestAct . reverse
 where earliestAct = ...
```

Now, this can be implemented either

- By simple pattern-matching recursion down the list:

  ```
     earliestAct [] = Nothing
     earliestAct (Message t user' txt : msgs)
           | user' == user  = Just txt
           | otherwise      = earliestAct msgs
  ```
- Or: as I said this is just a standard search. So why not use the standard [`find`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:find) function!

  ```
     earliestAct = fmap _messageContent . find ((==user) . _userName)
  ```

  here, I've used the `Functor` instance of `Maybe` to extract the content from the found message, if there is any at all.

Comment: TY for that nice answer!
You are right! But I´m a beginner, just did a couple of tasks yet and I`m happy if it works - no metter how effective it is xD
I really need to get away of that iterativ way of thinking.. THX

Answer (score 2):

Just add … `Just` :v

```
latestActivity :: UserName -> [Message] -> Maybe AbsoluteTime
latestActivity _ [] = Nothing 
latestActivity x y = 
    if x == _userName (last y)
        then Just (_timeStamp (last y))
        else latestActivity x (init y)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `else latestActivity x (init y)`?

Comment: omg.. ty ^^ I already tried to put "Just" on that position but it didn`t work.. so after correcting the brackets the way you did it works fine. THX